# Kotlin multiplatform mobile ktor logging not display request params in logcat

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I'm trying to see logs for httpRequest params, header, response etc. using ktor logging but i couldn't see any logs in logcat :(

The code block is showing below:

```
private val httpClient = HttpClient {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(
            Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                useAlternativeNames = false
            }
        )

        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.DEFAULT
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

** Using libs:

```
val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see log messages in Logcat, implement the `Logger` class by delegating logging to the `Log.d()` method:

```
val client = HttpClient {
    install(Logging) {
        logger = object : Logger {
            override fun log(message: String) {
                Log.d("HTTP call", message)
            }
        }
        level = LogLevel.ALL
    }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! thx a lot Aleksei

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using **[Kermit](https://kermit.touchlab.co/docs/)** I did

```kotlin
private fun provideKtorClient(): HttpClient = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json { isLenient = true; ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
    }
    install(Logging) {
        logger = object : Logger {
            override fun log(message: String) {
                co.touchlab.kermit.Logger.d { message }
            }

        }
        level = LogLevel.INFO
    }
}
```